# Weather graph using Angular 2, chart.js and json data

Tags: json, angular, chart.js, angular-cli

Using weather information that i receive from a service, i am trying to create a graph by means of chart.js.

I imported Chart into my project, and i am capable of using it using static data, but i am unable to use the data that i get from json.

What i am trying currently looks like this:

```
getForeCast()
{
    this.weatherService.getForecastByCityName(this.searchString)
        .subscribe(response =>
        {
            this.lineChartData = response.list.main.temp;
            this.lineChartLabels = response.list.dt;
        })
}

//LineChart
public lineChartData: Array<any>
public lineChartLabels: Array<any>
```

the getforecast() is activate in ngOnInit

the info that i receive from the json looks like this:

```
{
    "cod": "200",
    "message": 0.0054,
    "cnt": 35,
    "list": [
        {
            "dt": 1498748400,
            "main": {
                "temp": 21.87,
                "temp_min": 21.25,
                "temp_max": 21.87,
                "pressure": 1006.93,
                "sea_level": 1009.32,
                "grnd_level": 1006.93,
                "humidity": 62,
                "temp_kf": 0.62
            },
            "weather": [
                {
                    "id": 803,
                    "main": "Clouds",
                    "description": "broken clouds",
                    "icon": "04d"
                }
            ],
            "clouds": {
                "all": 56
            },
            "wind": {
                "speed": 6.81,
                "deg": 227.001
            },
            "rain": {},
            "sys": {
                "pod": "d"
            },
            "dt_txt": "2017-06-29 15:00:00"
        },
```

if i use the info to show it in a table, it works, but i can not get it to work in the graph.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `update()` method of the chart. Maybe you need to trigger it after you update your data in order for the chart to re-render.